# Stuck With if Statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, model-view-controller

This is my Code:

```
 if (haveDataDay) {
    @if (valueDateDay <=100) { 
        valueDateDay.ToString();
    } else if (valueDateDay > 100) {
        @valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "C2")
    }
} else {
    @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata")
}
```

Im trying to check if "valueDateDay" has a decimal value of "100 or less" then only change it to string to this line:

```
valueDateDay.ToString();
```

and if the "valueDateDay" is bigger than 100 then it need to check this statement and convert it to string:

```
@valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "C2") }
```

and if the "valueDateDay" value has no data or equals 0 then get0s to this line:

```
 else 
        { @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata") }
```

however when i run my code my values bigger than 100 are asigned correctly but the values of 100 or less are not saved going directly to :

```
  else 
        { @this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata") }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your brace formatting makes me want to stab my eyes out.

Comment: Note the cleaned up formatting. Your code is a syntax error, unless you haven't shown everything that's relevant.

Comment: `valueDateDay.ToString();` does not change `valueDateDay` to string, it *returns* a new string that is `valueDateDay` as a string. You need to assign it to something. `var valueDateDayAsAString = valueDateDay.ToString();`.

Comment: Fixed your formatting to save the eyes of friendly programmers.

Comment: What's the point of `@` in your code?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen presumably because it is contained in an mvc view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your braces are formatted the wrong way, so the else is out of the `if-else` continuum.

```
 if (haveDataDay) {
    if (valueDateDay <=100 && valueDataDay > 0) { 
        valueDateDay.ToString();
    } else if (valueDateDay > 100) {
        valueDateDay.ToString(valueDateDay % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "C2")
    } else {
        this.FP("lbl.loader.nodata")
    }
}
```

Also, `valueDateDay` smaller or equal to 0 will go in the first loop, so add the condition that it is greater than zero: `valueDateDay <=100 && valueDataDay > 0`.

Comment: thank bro , just realized that i only make the bracers like this so i could se better who it was formatted but ended up formatting them wrong thank its working now